# List initialialization with a first element and an additional collection

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, guava

Is there a **shorthand way** (may be guava or any lib) to initialize a Java **List** like this?

```
List list = MagicListUtil.newArrayList(firstElement, moreElementsList);
```

Comment: are you looking for mutable lists or immutable list?

Comment: it doesn't matter

Comment: @Naman the question asked here is not the same as the one suggested as duplicate: here, the idea is to concatenate elements with collections!

Comment: Solution using Eclipse Collections. List<String> list = Lists.mutable.with("1").withAll(Arrays.asList("2", "3", "4"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Guava offers several possibilities

### If you have arrays, use [`Lists.asList(...)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/28.1-jre)

```
String first = "first";
String[] rest = { "second", "third" };
List<String> list = Lists.asList(first, rest);
```

### If you have lists or other `Iterables`, use [`FluentIterable.of(...).append(...).toList()`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/28.1-jre/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#append-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
String first = "first";
List<String> rest = Arrays.asList("second", "third");
List<String> list = FluentIterable.of(first).append(rest).toList();
```

## But you can do that in Java 8 as well

Even though, it's way more verbose, but still...

### With an array

```
String first = "first";
String[] rest = { "second", "third" };
List<String> list = Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(rest))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### With a Collection

```
String first = "first";
List<String> rest = Arrays.asList("second", "third");
List<String> list = Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), rest.stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can simply use the java.util.Arrays class for single and multiple elements.

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third");
```

You can use the java.util.Collections for a list with a single element.

```java
List<String> strings = Collections.singletonList("first");
```

Comment: This is not the answer because the first should be an item, and the second should be a collection or list.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna copy list, you can do it by constructor like this

```
List<Float> oldList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Float> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```